# When does it make sense to pass true for needsReschedule in the jobFinished method of a JobService

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

When a `JobService` finishes and we did work in a background thread, we call `jobFinished` to let the system know our work is over and it can release the wakelock.
`jobFinished` takes a boolean `needsReschedule` as it's 2nd argument and when we pass true, it get's rescheduled according to the backoff criteria. But if we want to have a periodic job, we use `setPeriodic` on our `JobInfo` object. On the other hand we don't call `jobFinished` for a cancelled job and the return value of the `onStopJob` already defines wether or not we want to reschedule the job. 
So when does it make sense to ever pass `true` for `needsReschedule` on a finished job?

Example:

```
public class ExampleJobService extends JobService {
private static final String TAG = ExampleJobService.class.getSimpleName();
boolean jobCancelled = false;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job started");
    doBackgroundWork(params);

    return true;
}

private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Running: " + i);
                if (jobCancelled) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
    jobCancelled = true;
    return true;
}
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void scheduleJob(View v) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, ExampleJobService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
            .build();

    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
    if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
    }
}

public void cancelJob(View v) {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    scheduler.cancel(1);
    Log.d(TAG, "Job canceled");
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the documentation doesn't seem to specify it, as `needsReschedule` is related to the job's backoff criteria, I see them as a retry mechanism.

In cases where the background work fails (it could be because of an HTTP request that failed, for example), you may want to retry before the next expected execution of the job. That's when you pass `true` for `jobFinished`'s `needsReschedule`.